# Let’s get a taxi home after the concert

Tags: sentence-construction

> Let’s get **a taxi home** after the concert.

As I understand it, that sentence is correct, but I can't understand the bunch of the words: **"taxi home"**. Why we don't have a preposition between them? Because of the specific word "home"? For example, "get home", but "get to work".
So, if I change "home" to "work", then the sentence would be:

> Let’s get **a taxi to work**.

Right?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, No, it doesn't answer. My question was about the phrase "get a taxi home" and its usage.

Comment: Your question asks: **Why we don't have a preposition between them?** You even say "So, if I change "home" to "work", then the sentence would be: Let's get a taxi **to** work." So, it's clear the question is focused on why there is a missing preposition.

Comment: I am voting to close as Mari-Lou has already pointed to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Let’s get a taxi home after the concert.*

A  number of words like "home" can suggest a spatial complement, directional or locative, in which case they are best classified as prepositions.

In your example. "home" has the directional meaning: "to our place of residence". Thus the directional meaning of "to" is already incorporated in the meaning of "home". Compare also *Kim is coming home*, meaning "Kim is coming to her place of residence".

"Home" can also have a locative meaning. For example "KIm is home", where "home" means "in her place of residence".

> *Let’s get a taxi to work.*

Here, "work" does not have a directional meaning like "home" does. It simply means "our place of employment", thus the directional preposition "to" is required.

Answer (score 3):

Purely idiomatic.

We just don't say "to home".

In the morning:

- "I'm going to work".

In the evening:

- "I'm going home."

Next morning:

- "I'm going back to work."

Again that evening:

- "I'm going back home."

And so on.

It's not unique to home. There are other cases where "to" is not needed:

- "I'm going next door."

Can't immediately think of any others like that.

Comment: It's because "home" is really a preposition meaning "to our place of residence". Thus the directional preposition "to" is already included here in the meaning of "home".

Comment: @BillJ Did you mean to reply to OP?

Comment: @PrimeMover Looks like he's addressing you and your statements that it's "purely idiomatic" and that we "just don't say 'to home' ". BillJ states this is not the case, that there's a grammatical reason for it.

Comment: @BillJ Is "home" a preposition or a *preposition phrase*? I don't see how "home" can be a simple preposition since you can't put an object after it

Comment: It's a PP. The contrast of transitive vs intransitive can be applied to prepositions as well as to verbs. The intransitive preps often occur as particles. For example, in "She brought down the cases", the particle "down" is a preposition, an intransitive one of course since it is a one-word phrase.